# Can I get slot number if I have bus address

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, pci-e

In linux/pci.h file there are these macros defined

```
 /*
 *  7:3 = slot
 *  2:0 = function
 */
#define PCI_DEVFN(slot, func)   ((((slot) & 0x1f) << 3) | ((func) & 0x07))
#define PCI_SLOT(devfn)     (((devfn) >> 3) & 0x1f)
#define PCI_FUNC(devfn)     ((devfn) & 0x07)
```

From this line `*   7:3 = slot`

It looks like its meant that 5 bits can represent slot number. So I like to know is this correct.. OR its just someone wrote it and it says something else means its not slot number

Can anyone please guide me on this

I have a situation that I like to read slot number where the pcie device is physically plugged into pcie slot on motherboard slot. the above does make sense though,then may be checking out pciutils code and see what sys file its reading and get the bus address and based on that find the slot using this logic.. So I will need devfn which I believe is same as device function so I can read that from DMI or something. Can anyone please tell me that slot number of plugged in pcie slot can be read using above macro or just extracting it from bus address some how can anyone guide me on this thanks
SO

Reading the DMI document makes no sense it says the slot number is one byte field but the above macro contradicts that and says in kernel source that its 5 bits to represent slot number..

Comment: That's an encoded index for use in kernel structures See https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/pci.h#L321

Comment: `the DMI documen` what document?

Comment: @KamilCuk DSP0134_3.1.0.pdf just Google it u will find it

Comment: The 'bus:slot.func' numbers are used for addressing PCI configuration space of PCI device ('bus' selects a PCI bus, 'slot' selects a PCI device on the bus, 'func' selects a function on the PCI device). A multi-function PCI device can be split into up to 8 functions (each with their own configuration space), but function 0 is always present. This does not really have much to do with physical numbering of slots on the motherboard, but more to do with how the slots are wired up.

Comment: @IanAbbott if I have DMI type, length and handle fields then can I somehow read configuration space for pcie device? What to do for this?

Comment: The `lspci -vmm` command can show the physical slot number as 'PhySlot: *num*' if it can work it out. I believe it reads the /sys/bus/pci/slots/*/address entries where the wildcard * is the physical slot number and the "address" is in the form "DDDD:BB:SS" corresponding to PCI domain, bus and slot number of a PCI device. I don't think there is a very clean way to get this information from a kernel device driver.

Comment: From userspace, the `pci_fill_info` and `pci_get_string_property` functions in libpci can be called, both with the `PCI_FILL_PHYS_SLOT` value (which can be combined with other bits for `pci_fill_info`). `pci_fill_info` fills in info for a PCI device. `pci_get_string_property` retrieves previously filled information for a property of the PCI device.

Comment: @IanAbbott `sys/bus/pci/slots/` for pci. Is it same for pci express. Can u please tell I could not find this file. And I am told 4 pcie express gpus are connected to slots on motherboard

Comment: `/sys/bus/pci/slots/*` has information for both PCI and PCIe slots.

Comment: @IanAbbott well this directory slots is empty nothing inside it. And DMI has wrong 0xFF written on bus number byte what this means. Can u please tell?

Comment: TBH, it is empty on my desktop machine too, but on a HP Proliant server machine it is filled in.

Comment: @IanAbbott can I assume slot number info and bus number must be somewhere in DMI file in sys directory? If its missing in the data structure for DMI type 9

Comment: @IanAbbott  I am on   `CPU.........: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU G3900 @ 2.80GHz (2 vCPU)` And slots directory is empty. So like to know on ur `HP Proliant server machine` the files in slots directory coming from DMI or because I am started to having a feeling that those bus numbers and slots number in DMI are not unused. means DMIDecode shows wrong bus address and lspci shows different bus numbers.

Comment: Various drivers in the kernel call `pci_create_slot()` to create an entry in "/sys/bus/pci/slot/". These include the built-in ACPI pci_slot driver (when `CONFIG_ACPI_PCI_SLOT=y`), the pci-hyperv driver (for Microsoft Hyper-V guest VMs),  and all the PCI/PCIe hotplug drivers. I don't know which one created the slot entries on my HP server.

Comment: On my desktop machine, I added `dyndbg="module pci_slot +p"` to the linux kernel boot command line to get kernel debug log output (from `dmesg`) from the ACPI pci_slot driver. This produces messages of the form `pci_slot: Checking slot on path: xxx` possibly followed by some error message. On mine, every slot got an error `pci_slot: _ADR returned 5 on xxx` or `pci_slot: _SUN returned 5 on xxx`. (The `5` corresponds to an `AE_NOT_FOUND` error.)

Comment: @IanAbbott what are  PCI/PCIe hotplug drivers?

Comment: Hotplug controllers allow PCI/PCIe cards to be physically removed (in a controlled manner) or inserted while the system is running.